# Where to write logic in nodejs express route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using 
https://github.com/diegohaz/rest/ boilerplate
 and I do not fully get what the best practice is to put my logic like QR generation and extra validation.

I was thinking of putting validation and password generation in `index.js` How can I add logic in here? Never seen this type of function before.

`

```
router.post('/',
  token({ required: true }),
  body({ link, reward, accountid, message, startdate, enddate }),
  create);
```

Or do I write it in the controller and call an import an `qrcodeservice.js` file. And where can I put logic in this function? Also quite a new type of function for me.

```
export const index = ({ querymen: { query, select, cursor } }, res, next) =>
  Key.count(query)
    .then(count => Key.find(query, select, cursor)
      .then((keys) => ({
        count,
        rows: keys.map((key) => key.view())
      }))
    )
    .then(success(res))
    .catch(next)
```

I do get the flow of the program and understand the models (some validation is done in there).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can write the code in index.js which may be a good way to start developing. As the app grows it would be a good idea to move the code to other files to follow some organized pattern eg Model View Controller.

Comment: Cant seem to figure out where to put logic, can you help me how I can rewrite the code in index.js to use normal logic like fiddling with the parameters and calling other functions? I would like to maintain the standard and correct way of using express.

Comment: I am quite new to node development. I am using express including the express application generator. That seems similar to the diegohaz/rest system. One thing I noticed is that the diegohaz app wants to install globally as opposed to just in a specific app directory. Not sure if I would want that. Just wondering why you are using diegohaz not express? Steve

Comment: Apologies: I have just noticed the express application generator is installed globally!